# Ошибка с методом: 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java

При вызове метода person в классе classname(newclass), выдает ошибку:

> error: 'void' type not allowed here

Main.java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        classname newclass = new classname();
        System.out.println(newclass.person().name);
    }
}
```

classname.java

```
public class classname
{
    String name = "Игорь";

    public void person() {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы вызываете метод, который возвращает `void`, а затем пытаетесь получить у этой пустоты поле name. Если вы хотите сделать конструктор - вы должны назвать его точно также как вы назвали класс. Также в методе `person` вы просто присваивает значение поля `name` самому себе, если хотите устанавливать это поле через метод или конструктор - передайте требуемое значение в качестве аргумента.